# Regular Expression in numbers and string length Android

Tags: android, regex

I need to point out the users that a number can only start from `9` and and its length is to be exactly equal to 10 digits. How do I manipulate this with a `regex` ? Please don't mind the question, I am relatively new.

Comment: Show some of your attempts and why they did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate that the input is exactly 10 digits, starting with 9, use:

```
/^9\d{9}$/
```

The ^9 part matches a starting 9, {d}9 matches 9 digits

Answer (score 2):

Here you are. A simple solution (not with regex):

```
String number = "12345";
...
if (number.length() != 10 || number.startsWith("9") == false)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your input.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope this helps. Write if you have any problems.

Comment: Should be an `||` and OP is asking for a regex. Simply stating `not with regex` doesn't cut it.

Comment: Why should be ||? && is used, when you want, both sides be true.

Comment: `I need to point out the users that a number can only start from 9 **and** its length is to be exactly equal to 10 digits`. What happens when `number.length != 10`? Show the toast. What happens when `!number.startsWith("9")`? Show the toast. Yeah, should be an `||`.

Comment: Yep yep yep. Sorry. You are right. I was in a hurry so... Thanks. Edited.